# How we save validate child record in rails nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I didn't find any way regarding below issue:

if we have 10 child records in our nested form and 9 records have not any validation errors but only a single child record has some validation error like validate presence of.

In that case parent and 9 records should save in our DB and only 1 child is not saved.

do we have any option to achieve this scenario?

it would be very help full for me, thanks in advance.